# can i chain redux promsie action in react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a redux action which get data from server my action is like this

```
export const getFakeData = () => (dispatch) => {
  return dispatch({
    type: 'GET_FAKE_DATA',
    payload: {
      promise: axios.get('/test'),
    }
  });
};
```

my reducer is like this

```
const reducer = (INITIAL_STATE, {
  [GET_FAKE_DATA]: {
    PENDING: () => ({
      isLoading: true,  
    }),
    FULFILLED: (state, action) => {
      const { data } = action.payload.data;                 
      return {
        ...state,
        data,
        error: false,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    },
    REJECTED: () => ({
      isLoading: false,  
      error: true
    }),
});
```

I want to show success alert after my action sent, is below code breaks the principle of redux about one way flow?

```
this.props.getFakeData().then(() => {
  this.setState({
    showAlert: true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your use-case, **it's perfectly fine** to keep `showAlert` flag in the component's local state, instead of the Redux store.

Here's what [Redux official documentation](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate) stands for:

> Using local component state is fine. As a developer, it is your job to
>   determine what kinds of state make up your application, and where each
>   piece of state should live. Find a balance that works for you, and go
>   with it.
>
> Some common rules of thumb for determining what kind of data should be
>   put into Redux:
>
> - Do other parts of the application care about this data?
> - Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this original data?
> - Is the same data being used to drive multiple components?
> - Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given point in time (ie, time travel debugging)?
> - Do you want to cache the data (ie, use what's in state if it's already there instead of re-requesting it)?

Comment: thanks so much but this pattern break one way flow rule beacuse i connect my component to redux store too, do you think is it right?

Comment: **Yes, it's fine**. Please check again the above common rules of thumb. They cover most of the cases. Also please read the link I mentioned: [Do I have to put all my state into Redux? Should I ever use React's setState()?](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate)